# Как в bootstrap 5 сделать, чтобы меню-гамбургер при расрывании не двигало контент

Tags: bootstrap

На разрабатываемом лендинге http://cl46124.tmweb.ru есть мобильное меню-гамбургер, которое при раскрытии смещает логотип и все идущие за ним блоки вниз  http://prntscr.com/16ahz7s . Хотелось бы, чтобы меню раскрывалось поверх логотипа, то есть, без каких-либо смещений контента.

Код меню:

```html
<div class="topmenu">
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                                <div class="container">
                                    
                                     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                     <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                                     </button>
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Каталог цветов</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Акции</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">О компании</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Специальное предложение</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Отзывы</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
                                        </li>                                     
                                    </ul>
                                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
                        </div>
```

Comment: поверх это z-индекс и абсолютное позиционирование

Comment: Для какого именно класса нужно прописывать z-index и position: absolute ?